# Objects from swiftyjson - how to better handle empty values?

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have model object

```
class Person  {
  var name:String?
  var lastName:String?
  var adresss:String?
}
```

From server I get json response which contains array of persons. Problem is that some persons has values inside name, some json objects even doesnt have field name.

While dealing with json I itereate on JSON(data:data) and create an object for each person.

Seems that some persons will have empty names.

How to better deal with this situation so in future my program will not crash after reference to person who doesnt have name. Make a default value in class initializarion ? Or unwrap each field of person when dealing with each instance ?

Comment: Provide an example how do you want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

When you have you `json` data you should use `guard`. For example:

```
guard let name = json["name"] as? String,
    let lastName = json["lastName"] as? String,
    let address = json["address"] as? String else { // Do what you like here if it fails for some of these values}
```

In this way if all three values succeeds you can use the variables `name`, `lastName` and `address`.

If you want to set an empty value and continue every time you could:

```
let name = json["name"] as String ?? "" etc..
```

I prefere the first way though.

Answer (score 0):

In swift in order to safe unwrap nil value you may use '?' or 'if let',  ' guard let'  expressions. 
They can help to avoid nil values. 
To force unwrap use '!', but it may couse an exception

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you want to achieve. You have different possibilities.

**Discarding Person with empty values**

In this case you can discard `Person` if they don't have valid information. You can change your code:

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    let lastName: String
    let address: String
}
```

When you receive the json, you can simply guard against invalid values:

```
guard 
    let name = jsonName as? String,
    let lastName = jsonLastName as? String,
    let address = jsonAddress as? String else { return }
```

**Saving Person with optional values**

In this case you can use your own class with optional values but every time you use them you need to check for them.

```
class Person {
    var name: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var address: String?
}
```

You can save properties with:

```
person.name = jsonName
person.lastName = jsonLastName
person.address = jsonAddress
```

Even if `jsonName`, `jsonLastName` or `jsonAddress` your code will work since you declared them as an optional.

**Saving Person with default values**

In this case you can use your own class with optional values but every time you use them you need to check for them.

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var lastName: String
    var address: String
}
```

You can save properties with:

```
person.name = jsonName ?? ""
person.lastName = jsonLastName ?? ""
person.address = jsonAddress ?? ""
```

If `jsonName`, `jsonLastName` or `jsonAddress` are nil then the default value "" will be saved. Variables are not optional anymore, so you don't have to check them.